# NGINX 502 Bad Gateway Connect() failed (133: No route to host) while connecting to up stream

Tags: nginx

### Introduction

Hello, I'm having an issue setting up Nginx for a test website. I have a host and a vm, on the vm a docker application is running on port 3000.

### Problem

Now when I do 192.168.1.22:4444 (HOST MACHINE) 502 Bad Gateway appears. Also, no packets seem to be hitting the VM I set up.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 'port 4444'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
2 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

But now when I enter the VM's ip (172.16.1.22) and service port (4444) into my browser I receive packets.

```
14:49:46.860869 IP .3458 > .4444: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 211139829 ecr 9802156], length 0
14:49:46.860911 IP .3458 > .4444: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 211139829 ecr 9802157], length 0
14:49:46.861545 IP .3458 > .4444: Flags [P.], seq 492:944, ack 244, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 211139829 ecr 9802133], length 452
14:49:46.862192 IP .3458 > .4444: Flags [P.], seq 1:451, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 211139830 ecr 9802156], length 450
14:49:46.862248 IP .3458 > .4444: Flags [P.], seq 1:450, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 211139830 ecr 9802157], length 449
14:49:46.862306 IP .4444 > .4444: Flags [.], ack 451, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 9802158 ecr 211139830], length 0
```

### Question

Is there a configuration I missed, or can someone suggest how I should fix this problem?

### Nginx /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
http{
        server {
        listen       4444;
        server_name  vm3;

                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://172.16.1.22;
                        # re-send the host header - this may not be necessary
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        # set the X-Forwarded-For header, so that the public IP of the client is available to the backend server
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                }
        }
}
```

### /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2019/05/26 17:09:02 [error] 12276#12276: *81 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.22, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.16.1.22:80/", host: "192.168.1.10:32322"
```

Comment: What is the network between the two hosts?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I suspect this by default a bridge was made. I did not configure one 3: `virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
  
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0`

Comment: Neither of the IP addresses you listed is in that subnet! Please stop and describe the entire setup and give all of the details.

Comment: Sorry, @MichaelHampton this should be the virtual bridge `5: virbr1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.16.1.1/24 brd 172.16.1.255 scope global virbr1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
` I'll try and draw the topology give me a few

Comment: You need to either start the VM or check that its IP address hasn't changed.

Comment: This is the ip of the VM and it's running the application in Docker `2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.16.1.22/24 brd 172.16.1.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you specify the upstream port.

```
http{
        server {
        listen       4444;
        server_name  vm3;

                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://172.16.1.22:3000;
                        # re-send the host header - this may not be necessary
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        # set the X-Forwarded-For header, so that the public IP of the client is available to the backend server
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: removing  "proxy_set_header Host $host;" line resolved the problem on my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the port was closed, I checked via telnet, after configuring the firewall, the error went away